# Premium voices not available for text-to-speech in Twilio Console?

Tags: twilio

When I go to configure text-to-speech in Twilio Console I don't seem to be getting any of the premium voices advertised in the [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech). Why might that be?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my own account and can confirm that the premium voices are indeed missing from the drop-down choices in the Console's testing app.

However, if it helps, the default voice isn't really a useful feature as you should specify the voice on every Say command using [Twiml](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#twiml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <Response>
        <Say language="en-US" voice="Polly.Joanna">Hello. I am Joanna and I speak American English!
        </Say>
    </Response>
```

Specifying the voice and working directly with the Twiml will be necessary as you build apps and need to correct pronounciation and add pauses using [SSML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#ssml).

Anytime you use a Say command, even in Studio, you can specify whichever voice you prefer - just not in the Console's testing app. You could try opening a ticket with Twilio for them to correct.